# Chrome 75 bug?: HTMLInputElement elements are not garbage collected when a text is written

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory-leaks

I am programatically removing HTMLInputElement from DOM. 
Then I run heap dump and those HTMLInputElements aren't in heap dump.

However when I type into HTMLInputElement, then HTMLInputElement is not garbage collected and I can see it in heap dump (in Constructors).

If there are attached handlers to these elements, related objects are not discarded from memory either.

Observed in Chrome 75.

Seems IE11 is not experiencing the issue.

```
<html>
<body>

<button id="button">Add</button>
<div id="container"></div>

<script>

    var button = document.getElementById("button");
    var cont = document.getElementById("container");

    button.addEventListener("click", function() {
        if (cont.childNodes.length > 0) {
            cont.removeChild(cont.childNodes[0]);
        }
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "text";
        cont.appendChild(input)
    })

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I would expect that those elements will be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

Happens to me as well - version 75.0.3770.142 (64 bit).

However, randomly chosen old build of 32 bit chromium -  69.0.3450.0 - doesn't seem to be sufferering from this issue.

The build is here: https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Win/564085/